# OSX linking non-universal (i386) w/ universal .dylib

Tags: macos, linker, universal

Is this legal?  I'm getting an error "Can't find <lib>.framework/Versions/4/<lib>" from the linker.  In this case, <lib> is 'QtGui' that has been built as an i386 framework (not universal), but another (third party) lib I'm linking to (that uses QtGui) *is* universal.

I'm thinking everything has to be built universal or not...

Answer (score 0):

You can link a non-universal framework (say i386 only) with a universal framework (say with i386 and x86_64) to make an i386 binary.

Of course you can't make an x86_64 binary in this case.

Note that if your Mac has a 64 bit CPU, the linker defaults to mae an x86_64 binary. So the linker will complain if any of your library does not have the x86_64 part. If you want to create an i386 binary, you need to specify that explicitly on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Roger.

Turns out my issue actually stems from bad embedded paths in the external libraries that have to be reset (which I didn't think would affect links, but it does).

The universal build issue was a suspected culprit, but no.

Thanks,
rickb